# how can I "Save As" after I finish recording (in Action)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, actions

So Recently I learnt how to record my action on Photoshop. it went smoothly and everything.

But, I am having problems while saving. When I record my "Saving As" action and press play. It doesn't ask me what name I want for the piture, it just saves the picture as the last name you saved.

for example, I have 30 photos that I want to do X and Y to them and save them. I recorded my action for the first photo and I saved it as "Edited1". when I press Play to the 2nd image, it does X and Y to it. But it also store it as "Edited1" (i.e. store it in the place of the previews photo).

what can I do? I remember photoshop used to ask me abou the name everytime I press play on ACTION. but now it just names it by itself :(

Answer (score 1):

Check the box next to the *Save* command in the Actions Palette and Photoshop will stop and prompt you with the "Save As" Dialog box.

[image]

By default the box is unchecked. You need to toggle the dialog to "On".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, the "save as" was saved as a part of your action with the "Edited1" name you assigned the original image when you recorded the action.

If you want the save as command to allow you to enter a custom name each time, you should remove the recorded "save as" command from your action, and instead insert the "save as" command as a Menu Item.

From your Actions palette, click the upper right "hamburger" menu, then select "Insert Menu Item". A small dialogue box will come up, but all you'll need to do is select File > Save As, which will insert it in that dialogue box. Click "OK" and the Save As command should be added to your action. Now when you run it, the action will pause on the Save As dialogue box to allow you to customize the name/settings.